# column sorting in named sets power pivot (MDX)

Tags: mdx

i need help sorting columns in named sets created in power pivot
-data source is just plain .txt files on sharepoint

for example i have named set

```
  {([Measures].[Sum of broj_stavki_KKPPL]),
    ([Measures].[prosečan broj iskomisioniranih stavki KP i PL]),
    ([Measures].[procenat učinka komisionara na KP i PL])}
```

and i need formula to sort second column or even better if i can get multiple sort for all columns

i have tried to use function ORDER but as i'm new to MDX function i just can get it right